# NEXT_DAY in Crystal Reports

Tags: oracle, datetime, crystal-reports, formula

Is there anything like the Oracle "NEXT_DAY" function available in the syntax that Crystal Reports uses?

I'm trying to write a formula to output the following Monday @ 9:00am if the datetime tested falls between Friday @ 9:00pm and Monday @ 9:00am.

So far I have

```
IF DAYOFWEEK ({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) IN [7,1]
    OR (DAYOFWEEK({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) = 6 AND TIME({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) in time(21,00,00) to time(23,59,59))
    OR (DAYOFWEEK({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) = 2 AND TIME({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) in time(00,00,00) to time(08,59,59))
THEN ...
```

I know I can write seperate IF statements to do a different amount of DateAdd for each of Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon, but if I can keep it concise by lumping all of these into one I would much prefer it. I'm already going to be adding additional rules for if the datetime falls outside of business hours on the other weekdays so I want to do as much as possible to prevent this from becoming a very overgrown and ugly formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no CR equivalent that I know of, you can just cheat and borrow the `NEXT_DAY()` function from the Oracle database. You can do this by creating a SQL Expression and then entering something like:

```
-- SQL Expression {%NextDay}
(SELECT NEXT_DAY("MYTABLE"."MYDATETIME", 'MONDAY')
 FROM DUAL)
```

then you could either use that directly in your formula:

```
IF DAYOFWEEK ({MYTABLE.MYDATETIME}) IN [7,1]
    OR (DAYOFWEEK({MYTABLE.MYDATETIME}) = 6 AND TIME({MYTABLE.MYDATETIME}) in time(21,00,00) to time(23,59,59))
    OR (DAYOFWEEK({MYTABLE.MYDATETIME}) = 2 AND TIME({MYTABLE.MYDATETIME) in time(00,00,00) to time(08,59,59))
THEN DateTime(date({%NextDay}),time(09,00,00))
```

Or, the *even better* way would be to just stuff ALL of the logic into the SQL Expression and do away with the formula altogether.

Comment: Been really busy with other projects today, but I will try this out tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Considering Sunday is 1
- And the first 7 is the week we want to back

  7  = 1 week
  14 = 2 weeks
- The last Number (1) is 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, 3 for Tuestday

Last Sunday 1 week ago
Today - 7 + ( 7 - WEEKDAY(TODAY)   )+1

Last Monday 2 weeks ago
Today - 14 + ( 7 - WEEKDAY(TODAY)   )+2

So this 2 formulas give me MONDAY LAST WEEK and SUNDAY LAST WEEK.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
EvaluateAfter({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) ;
If DayOfWeek ({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) In [crFriday,crSaturday,crSunday,crMonday]
then
IF DayOfWeek ({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) In [crFriday] 
AND TIME({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) >= time(21,00,00)
then //your code here
Else if Not(DayOfWeek ({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) In [crFriday] )
AND (TIME({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) >= time(00,00,00) AND TIME({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) <= time(23,59,59))
then //your code here
Else if DayOfWeek ({DATETIMEFROMMYDB})In [crMonday] 
AND TIME({DATETIMEFROMMYDB}) < time(09,00,00)
then //your code here
```

Comment: I think the "if not Friday" and "if Monday" clauses need to be reversed. Otherwise a record stamped Monday 12pm for example would get picked up in the middle of this statement by matching the "not Friday and between 00:00 and 23:59" filter.

Comment: if you think post is helpful... reverse the clause and try

Comment: @Downvoter... comments whats wrong with the formula it is a tested one and worked for me...